# Efficient search for a Triples data

Tags: nlp, similarity, information-retrieval

I have a text file which consists of ~10k triples in the format,

Let say I need to extract all the relevant triples for the query "Tom and Jerry likes to play football", with this I am extracting NP(Noun Phrases) from the query and applying similarity search.

It takes a lot of time ~10 minutes to fetch the results and it isn't a scalable solution since, the size of triple file is directly proportional to search time.

How can I reduce the time?